# TensorFlow functional too slow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have created a TensorFlow model that processes 50 different images that belong to one observation. So A Batch has the form of `(32, 50, 128, 128, 1)`. The model is defined by:

```
input = layers.Input((50, 128, 128, 1))
sub_models = []
for mcol in range(50):
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(128, 128, 1))(input[:, mcol, :, :])
    x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
    x = layers.Flatten()(x)
    x = layers.Dense(128)(x)
    x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = layers.Dense(32)(x)
    sub_models.append(x)
combined = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(sub_models)
z = layers.Dense(1024)(combined)
z = layers.Dense(512)(z)
z = layers.Dense(512)(z)
z = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(z)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, z)
```

The model looks like this (simpler version with fewer inputs):
[Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epkeC.png)

And my train step is like below:

```
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    logits = model(x_batch_train[:, :50, :, :, None], training=True)
    loss_value = loss(Y, logits)
```

The problem is that the training step is super slow and takes few seconds for each step on a V100 GPU. I think the problem is with the for-loop. Is there a way to define the model in a smarter way that takes less time?

Comment: It's not for the loop in functional api, you should check this  https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you reformat your data into (32, 128, 128, 50), 50 channels, one for each image, You can remove the loop all together, by using the groups keyword argument (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D#args)

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers

input = layers.Input((50, 128, 128, 1))

# Reshape data (50, 128, 128, 1) -> (50, 128, 128)
x = tf.keras.backend.squeeze(input, axis=-1)
# Transpose (50, 128, 128) -> (128, 128, 50)
x = layers.Permute((2, 3, 1), input_shape=(50, 128, 128))(x)

# NOTE! The groups = 50 part is what breaks up the network
x = layers.Conv2D(32 * 50,
      kernel_size=(3, 3), input_shape=(128, 128, 50), groups=50)(x)
# Reshape to max pool 3D
# 126, 126, 50 * 32 -> 126, 126, 50, 32
x = layers.Reshape((126, 126, 50, 32))(x)

x = layers.MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 1))(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)

# Change (63, 63, 50, 32) -> (50, 63 * 63 * 32)
x = layers.Permute((3, 1, 2, 4), input_shape=(63, 63, 50, 32))(x)
x = layers.Reshape((50, 63 * 63 * 32))(x)

x = layers.Dense(128)(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(32)(x)

# Join everything together as per the spec
combined = layers.Flatten()(x)

z = layers.Dense(1024)(combined)
z = layers.Dense(512)(z)
z = layers.Dense(512)(z)
z = layers.Dense(2, activation="softmax")(z)
model = tf.keras.Model(input, z)
```

That being said, the loop itself should not be a speed bottleneck (ensure you are actually running on GPU), since you're just building the compute graph, but this should still speed things up.

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: The number of filters must be evenly divisible by the number of groups. Received: groups=50, filters=32
Should I simply change the number of filters?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I misread the documentation. Filters should be 32*50. Updated answer.

Comment: It works with only setting the number of filters to 32*50 but it fails in back-propagation!
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Computed input depth 50 doesn't match filter input depth 1 [Op:Conv2DBackpropInput]

Comment: Yeah, you need to change your input too. I can update this answer if you can't get it, but you'll want to remove the final channel (50,128,128,1)->(50,128,128), and then permute the axis so that 50 is the channel size (50,128,128) -> (128, 128, 50). You can do this as part of the model!

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you show me how it works! I'm still dealing with that error!
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:....

Comment: @Morty, did this ever work? I tested it out myself